# Are women obligated to say the morning blessings?

Tags: halacha, blessing, women, netilat-yadayim-washing

Are women obligated to say the morning blessings and perform the ritual hand washing?

Answer (score 4):

A responsum of the Geonim ([Sha'arei Teshuva 345](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30774&st=&pgnum=75)) says they are obligated to say the morning blessings. The Arukh haShulchan rules this way as well ([OC 70:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A2_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)), as does R Pesach Eliyahu Falk ([Machaze Eliyahu 13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21547&st=&pgnum=73)) interpreting the final ruling of the Mishna Berurah (70 sk 2) accordingly. Also ruling that women are obligated are Rs [Eliezer Melamed](http://ph.yhb.org.il/03-06-01/), Ovadia Yosef (Yechaveh Da'at 4:4) and his son [Yitzhak Yosef](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.52.17).

R [Ben Zion Abba Shaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Zion_Abba_Shaul) in his [Ohr leSion](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&st=&pgnum=58) rules they are not obligated.