# Does a woman have to say 100 brachot a day?

Tags: halacha, blessing, women

My rav says a woman has the obligation to recite a hundred benedictions a day.
Is this the view of the majority of poskim? What are the reasons?
The following are footnotes from [halachapedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Making_one_hundred_Brachot_daily):

---

- (Women are not obliged:) From  Halichot Bayta 13:note 2 in name of Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach,
  Sh”t Teshuvot VeHanhagot 2:129, Sh”t Shevet HaKehati 3:63, Birkat
  Eitan (pg 62), Vezot HaBracha (pg 185, chapter 20), Sh”t Ateret Paz
  1:1, Shevet HaLevi 5:23, and Sh”t Rivevot Efraim 3:47, 5:114 write
  that women are exempt and some base it on the Magen Avraham regarding
  Zecher Yetziat Mitzrayim in Shema who disagrees with the Shagat
  Aryeh.
- (Women are obliged) Rav Elyashiv in Yashiv Moshe (pg 19) and Birkat Eitan (pg 61),
  Rav Hershel Schachter in a shiur on yutorah.org ("Women at Prayer"
  min 28), Chacham Ovadyah in Halichot Olam (vol 1 pg 59), Halacha
  Brurah 46:8, and Yalkut Yosef (Otzar Dinim LeIsha 6:1 pg 75), and
  Halichot Bat Yisrael (end of chapter 14) write that women are
  obligated since it’s a obligation that applies the whole day and is
  renewed every day similar to the Shagat Aryeh regarding Zecher
  Yetziat Mitzrayim in Shema. Yalkut Yosef (Otzar Dinim LeIsha 6:1 pg
  75) cites some who say that after the fact women can fulfill their
  obligation with praises of Hashem or by answering Amen to the brachot
  of others. See Contemporary Questions In Halacha and Hashkafa pg. 106
  where he quotes opinions on both sides as well

Comment: Note answers here are not good substitutes for your rabbis advice. Anything you find here should be treated like you heard it from friends. Use it to go back and ask your rabbi about it if you want or just to learn some Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sure, just want to learn more. Due to language issues, rav and I cannot communicate at a comprehensive level using too many technical words or quoting too many sources on halacha, that's why I ask here :)

Comment: Women and men are obligated in all the same blessings (except for those said on time-bound Mitzvot, so on a regular day Shema/Tzitzit/Tefillin = 9 blessings) but still shouldn't be much of an issue getting to 100. I'm not sure why you'd think women and men would be different in this regard.

Comment: [Yalkut Yosef 46:3:5](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_all.html#HtmpReportNum0054_L2) says they are obligated. So too R Chaim Kanievsky (Shelat Rav chapter 17). Indeed I'm not aware of any Rishon who exempts women.

Comment: [Shevet HaLevi 5:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1415&st=&pgnum=27) says they must be exempt because the blessings for Tefillin on our the Beit Yosef's list. I don't follow the logic since Tefillin blessings aren't said every day anyway. The lists are just examples.

Comment: Great references, I ask as I saw from some sites arguing it's a time bound mitzvah (fn 12 of http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Making_one_hundred_Brachot_daily#cite_note-12 ). As a matter of practicality, since women are not obliged to attend the 3 public tefillot a day, I have doubts whether I do end up saying 100 blessings a day as a woman.

Comment: Unless you are a Chazzan or get an Aliyah, going to public Tefillah doesn't get you any more of the 100 blessings. Women have 19 morning blessings, 2 for Pesukei diZimra, 19*3=57 for Amida, ~12 on food, ~3 bathroom = 93. That's pretty close. So either say blessings on Shema or eat some extra candy.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in advance - why would that be 19*3 for amidah rather than 19 if Im only obliged to 1 tefillah a day? Is it that women generally say the amidah 3 times a day if they want to fulfill the mitzvah? I don't have enough common practice to refer to as the religious community where I live is tiny and consist mostly of baalei teshuva/rabbanit/gerim...

Comment: _If_ you are only obligated in 1 tefillah a day then indeed it wouldn't be 57. But that position was made up in the last ~century. No known classical authority before 500 years ago distinguishes women from men regarding an obligation to pray. At some point women werent praying (perhaps due to illiteracy) and someone tried to suggest ways their actions didnt necessarily contradict the explicit Mishna which obligates women in prayer. So yes, its not logically inconsistent that women aren't obligated in all 3 Tefilot/100 blessings a day, but it doesn't seem to be the dominant traditional position

Comment: @DoubleAA, it seems you have an answer. Might I suggest you post it as such.

Comment: @msh210 Na, the question has changed. I don't have an answer if there is a strict majority either way (it seems there's a fair amount on both sides and I'm doubtful such a claim is possible to defend) and i have the reason for one opinion but I don't really get it. Not answer material yet at least.

Comment: Note [women are obligated in morning blessings](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77246/759) which are essentially [there in order to help get to 100](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95).